# Pandas compare 3 columns and output the result if count more than 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns with value either A, B or C
I want to compare these 3 columns and give output which value have more than 1 counts. If the count is tie then the output will be "-"

Input:

```
    | col1  | col2  | col3  |
    |-------|-------|-------|
    | A     | A     | B     |
    | A     | B     | B     |
    | C     | B     | C     |
    | A     | B     | C     |
```

Output:

```
    | col1  | col2  | col3  | Result|
    |-------|-------|-------|-------|
    | A     | A     | B     | A     |
    | A     | B     | B     | B     |
    | C     | B     | C     | C     |
    | A     | B     | C     | -     |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try with `Counter` to get the most common element:

```
from collections import Counter

def most_common():
    for s in df.to_numpy():
        k, v = Counter(s).most_common(1)[0] 
        yield '-' if v == 1 else k

df['Result'] = list(most_common())
```

---

```
  col1 col2 col3 Result
0    A    A    B      A
1    A    B    B      B
2    C    B    C      C
3    A    B    C      -
```

Comment: Added another option @ShubhamSharma; hope that's ok with you.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma
this only works on the first tie found. after that all results become whatever in column 3

Comment: That's great @sammywemmy :)

Comment: @Aira Can you give a sample for such a case?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma using the example above, result for row 4 (A,B,C)  is "-" and then if row 5 is C,B,A then result will be A not "-" so when I do count afterwards, I only got 1 for "-"

Comment: @Aira There are always three columns i.e `col1`, `col2` and `col3` which needs to be consider, Right?

Comment: @Aira Edited the answer to account for such condition.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not a big concern, you can just write a row wise method that returns the value that appears more than once:

```
def appear_more_than_once(s):
    cnt = s.value_counts()
    if len(cnt) > 0 and cnt.iloc[0] > 1:
        return cnt.index[0]
    else:
        return '-'
        
df['Result'] = df.apply(appear_more_than_once, axis=1)
print(df)
#  col1 col2 col3 Result
#0    A    A    B      A
#1    A    B    B      B
#2    A    B    C      -
```

https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/4e5d36bc.py

Comment: not a big concern since the dataset is not too big and this works fine. thanks